# Creating a clean and proper Perl TK checkbox

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perl-data-structures

Is there a more efficient and less code way to do the below without making it too confusing? I want to make sure I track each value as I want to run seperate functions depending if $average_value was selected or possible all three options were selected. The program is a basic data analytical application to give you an idea.

EDIT:

Adding the following code, which makes it act like a boolean being that Perl does not use "TRUE" or "FALSE and instead uses ZERO or ONE values.

```
 $differences = $tab1 -> Checkbutton(
                      -text     =>      "Differences", 
                      -font     =>      \$fontdefault,
                      -variable =>      \$differences_value,

    $totalcheck = $average_value+$duplicates_value+$differences_value;
```

The code above is using -variable. I suppose addin the above may provide more information as to whether this was efficient coding or not--or possibly the shortest best method. Perl gets very confusing after hundreds of lines and I am trying to figure out the best methods possible.

ORIGINAL:

```
    if ($totalcheck <= 0 ) {
            my $d = $mw->Dialog(
            -title       =>     "ERROR: Blank", 
            -bitmap      => 'warning',
            -text        =>     "No selection made.", 
                );
                    $d->Show; 
            } else {
                        if ($average_value > 0) {
                            print "average\n"
                                }  
                        if ($duplicates_value > 0){
                                print "duplicates\n"
                                } 
                        if ($differences_value > 0){
                                print "differences\n"
                                } 
                }
```

Comment: I don't see much space for improvements. Maybe you should use boolean operations and conditions instead of arithmetic ones, e.g. `$totalcheck = $average_value || $duplicates_value || $differences_value`, `if (!$totalcheck)`, `if ($average_value)`.

Comment: Okay, that's a good idea. Thanks.